# activated venv - import error even though package is installed in the venv

Tags: python, linux, python-venv

i'm working on `python 3.7` with `Linux Ubuntu 18.04` and i'm trying to import a `requests` from the `venv` that i've created.

What I have done is install python3.7 and set it to the default via `vim ~/.bashrc`. When I type `python -V` in the terminal, it now prints `python 3.7.3`.

I've also installed `VirtualEnv` with this [tutorial](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000695551-Installing-and-using-virtualenv-with-Python-3) and installed the `venv` to my project directory. Within the project directory, I can clearly see that the `venv` as well as the other folders such as `bin`, `include`, `lib`, `share` folders have also been created. (`include` folder has python3.7m added to it). (`lib`/`python3.7`/`site-packages` also have the initial packages such as `pip`, `setuptools`, etc...)

What I did next was to use terminal and activate `venv` with `source venv/bin/activate`. From there I did a `pip install requests` and I can see that it have been installed in `venv`/`lib`/`python3.7`/`site-packages`.

**Problem**

while `venv` is still activated:

```
(venv) tinker@tinkerboard:~/jngm/Project Space/Crde$ python
Python 3.7.3 (default, Jun  5 2019, 14:36:28) 
[GCC 7.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
>>>
```

**However**:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.chdir('venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/')
>>> import requests
>>> a = requests.get(http://www.google.com')
>>>
```

What is happening that I cannot do a `import requests` directly?

*note: while `venv` is activated, i did a `pip install requests` and not a `sudo pip install requests` - as it was recommended by online tutorials.

**Edit**

`which python` **inside** venv: `/home/tinker/jngm/Project Space/Crde/venv/bin/python`

`which python` **outside** venv: `/usr/bin/python`

`which python3.7` **outside** venv: `/usr/local/bin/python3.7`

The below code shows the `sys.path` while `venv` is activated

```
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.path)
['', '/usr/local/lib/python37.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
>>> 

# while `venv` is activated:
>>> echo $PATH
>>> /home/tinker/jngm/Project Space/Crde/venv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

Comment: show the output of `which python` from both within and outside `venv`

Comment: Hello - I've updated the qns to show `which python` as well as `which python3.7` python 3.7 is what i am intending to use - not sure if there is an issue?

Comment: just using the terminal provided by ubuntu.

Comment: Why are you chdir into `venv`? Can you show your directory hierarchy? And where are you doing `source`?

Comment: Could you show us the result of `sys.path`?

Comment: @sraw - i've added the `sys.path` while `venv` is activated. could it be that it is picking up `site-packages` from `local/lib` instead of `venv`?

Comment: It doesn't look correct :( At least it shows that you're using the user-wide lib instead of `venv`-wide. How about the result of `sys.executable`?

Comment: `>>> print(sys.executable)` >>> `/usr/local/bin/python3.7`

Comment: @Sraw that wouldn't make any difference. I suspect the venv was activated from wrong directory. Or venv initialization was corrupted. But it doesn't explain why pip installs package into venv/lib.

Comment: "pip install requests" => should have been "pip**3** install requests" AFAICT - but this doesn't explain why the venv's lib directorory doesn't show up in your `sys.path`.

Comment: `venv` just manipulates your current environment variable `PATH`. I guess your `PATH` is not correctly set, could you then show us the result of your environment variable `PATH` when `venv` is activated?

Comment: Sorry but how do I show this to you @Sraw?

Comment: By `echo $PATH` in the terminal.

Comment: That's even more weird. Did you ever modify your `activate` script? There's only one explanation is that your `activate` script doesn't modify your shell variables. Either it's broken or your shell doesn't compatible with it.

Comment: :( No i did not modify `activate` one bit.. sigh..

Comment: Can you try a new venv `python3 -m venv test-env; cd test-env; source bin/activate; echo $PATH` and check `sys.path` again?

Comment: Also your `sys.path` doesn't contain `venv/bin` while `which python` does contain it is not possible! You may re-create a new virtualenv and validate the configuration.