# Why do python3 and python (alias to python3) use different import paths in a venv

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, python-venv

I am only just getting to grips with venvs and find it occasionally very confusing.

On my raspberry pi, numpy is installed in site packages, but also can show up in an isolated venv, which I think is inconsistent.

```
pi@zzz7:~ $ mkvenv test --no-sitepackages
pi@zzz7:~/ $ venv test
(test) pi@zzz7:~/ $ python -c "import numpy"
(test) pi@zzz7:~/ $ python3 -c "import numpy"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

So numpy is in the venv for python ... but not python3 ... Yet python and python3 seems to be the same.

```
(test) pi@zzz7:~/ $ python -V
Python 3.7.3
(test) pi@ztzz:~/ $ python3 -V
Python 3.7.3
```

Then after looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56457474/activated-venv-import-error-even-though-package-is-installed-in-the-venv?) related question I see that they are using different paths, which does explain the behaviour.

```
(test) pi@zzz7:~/ $ python -c "import sys;print(sys.path)"
['', '/usr/lib/python37.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.7', '/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', 
'/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages', '/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/si5351-1.2.3-py3.7.egg',
 '/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/smbus-1.1.post2-py3.7-linux-armv7l.egg', 
'/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
(test) pi@zzz7:~/ $ python3 -c "import sys;print(sys.path)"
['', '/usr/lib/python37.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.7', '/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', 
'/home/pi/.venv/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
```

The behaviour for python3 seems to me to be consistent with the --no-sitepackages environment.

So my question is why does the python invocation add the extra items to the path?

Also is there a way to avoid this?  (i.e. make python ... behave like python3 ...) Looking at ~/.venv/test/bin python seems to be an alias to python3 already, which would to me be a solution.

```
pi@zzz7:~/.venv/test $ ls bin -l
total 32
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 2195 Jan 15 09:20 activate
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 1251 Jan 15 09:20 activate.csh
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 2403 Jan 15 09:20 activate.fish
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pi pi  248 Jan 15 09:20 easy_install
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pi pi  248 Jan 15 09:20 easy_install-3.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pi pi  230 Jan 15 09:20 pip
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pi pi  230 Jan 15 09:20 pip3
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pi pi  230 Jan 15 09:20 pip3.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 pi pi    7 Jan 15 09:20 python -> python3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 pi pi   16 Jan 15 09:20 python3 -> /usr/bin/python3
```

Thank you for the suggestions. Further info

```
(test) pi@zzz7:~ $ ls -l $(which python)
lrwxrwxrwx 1 pi pi 7 Jan 15 09:20 /home/pi/.venv/test/bin/python -> python3
(test) pi@zzz7:~ $ ls -l $(which python3)
lrwxrwxrwx 1 pi pi 16 Jan 15 09:20 /home/pi/.venv/test/bin/python3 -> /usr/bin/python3
(test) pi@zzz7:~ $ which python
/home/pi/.venv/test/bin/python
(test) pi@zzz7:~ $ which python3
/home/pi/.venv/test/bin/python3
```

Comment: Can you please post the actual definitions of ``python`` and ``python3``? That's like the output of ``which python``, ``which python3``, ``ls -l $(which python)`` and ``ls -l $(which python3)``.

Comment: Have you tried calling `which python`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add this information with code formatting.